# Numbers of matrices satisfying certain property

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Initially we're given a fixed sequence $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, s.t. $a_i \le n; \forall i\le n$. Now we need to fill a $n \times n$ matrix with ones and zeroes, such that the matrix is symmetric and the sum in the first row/column is equal to $a_1$, the sum in the second row/column is equal to $a_2$ and so on. Find the number of ways to do this.

---

The fact that both the $i$-th row and the $i$-th column have to have the same sum is the difficult part for me. Also I tried to convert the matrix to a bipartite undirected labeled graph (columns in one set, rows in other set), but not much came out of this.

Comment: Presumably you want to find a matrix rather than feeling it?

Comment: Note that the number can be 0, even if all the $a_i$ are positive integers. I think in the jargon the sequence has to be a self-conjugate partition. Playing with small numbers it is surprisingly hard to get cases other than those where all the possibilities can be obtained from each other by permuting rows/cols.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Gale-Ryser theorem would be helpful here. It considers two different partitions (p, q) of the same number (n) such that a (0, 1) matrix has columns summing to p and rows summing to q.

For your case, of course p = q and it is necessary that the transpose of [p dominates p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order). There is a [proof here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975191?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that also gives a simple way to produce an example of such a matrix.

Should you need all such (0,1) matrices, there is a [paper by Miller and Harrison](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1375362560) which gives a method for sampling and enumerating them.